# Subtracting a dynamic date from a fixed date in Velocity (Marketo)

Tags: java, velocity, marketo

Using Velocity in Marketo (marketing automation software) I'd like to have a email token (velocity script) that gets the date on the user's computer and subtracts it from a fixed date.

So far, I have:

```
#set ($today = $date.getDate())
#set ($promoEnd = $convert.parseDate('2018-02-01', "yyyy-MM-dd"))
#set ($result = $date.difference ($promoEnd, $today).days)
#end
```

The date.difference function is supposed to subtract on variable from another, but I get an error when trying to send a sample email:

> An error occurred when procesing the email Body! Encountered "(" near
>
> ```
> #set ($promoEnd = $convert.parseDate('2018-02-01', "yyyy-MM-dd"))
> #set ($result = $date.difference ($promoEnd, $today).days)
> #end</p> 
>                                       </div></td> 
>                                   </tr>
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add `VelocityTools`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the Velocity parser doesn't like the space before the opening parenthesis, as long as the spaces after `#set`.

So just try:

```
#set($promoEnd = $convert.parseDate('2018-02-01', "yyyy-MM-dd"))
#set($result = $date.difference($promoEnd, $today).days)
```

and it should work.